# How do I get excel to return a match which meets at least 2 of 3 criteria?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I know how to find a cell that matches all 3 criteria:

```
{=INDEX(E5:E11,MATCH(1,(H5=B5:B11)*(H6=C5:C11)*(H7=D5:D11),0))}
```

Or to find a cell which matches any of 3 criteria:

```
{=INDEX(E5:E11,MATCH(1,(H5=B5:B11)+(H6=C5:C11)+(H7=D5:D11),0))}
```

But how do I make it return a value that matches 2 or more criteria - i.e. not necessarily all the criteria, but more than one criterion?

I don't object to using a different function to Index & Match if it works. I prefer formulas to VBA, though. I'm using Excel 2019.

My dataset has multiple records which would meet two or more of any given 3 criteria. I realise Index & Match will just return the first one, that's fine for this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `INDEX`/`MATCH` array function for this purpose. Actually, your second formula already comes close - you just need to add `>=2` as a criteria:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$6;MATCH(TRUE;(($B$2:$B$6=$G$2)+($C$2:$C$6=$G$3)+($D$2:$D$6=$G$4))>=2;0))
```

[image: INDEX/MATCH where at least 2 out of three criteria are True]

To understand how the formula works, you may have a look at this, "imaginary" array:

[image: Imaginary array]

Excel will add three arrays with `True`/`False` for each of your criteria and then add these. We then compare the result - if it is 2 or lager, it will be True and we can find the row number using the `MATCH` function.

As you already know, this function **only show the first result**. Depending on your version of Excel, you might need to enter the formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.